# AngularJS - show loading icon till csv file is downloaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, asp.net-web-api

I have AngularJS application , and I send to download svc file on server like this :

```
public static void DownloadCSV(string csvFile, string fileName)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
             "attachment; " +
             "filename=" + fileName + ".csv;" +
             "creation-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "; " +
             "modification-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "; " +
             "read-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(csvFile);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

in client side I send to  a webApi function called "exportToCsv" which use DownloadCSV function , in this way :

```
            var p = document.createElement('a')
            p.setAttribute('href', "myApp/exportToCsv" )
            p.click();
```

My problem is that I want to present a loading icon to the user untill the file finish to download.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Prepare an html with a loading icon(.gif probably) that is centered on screen, rest is shadowed maybe;

```
<div ng-show="loading" ng-include src="'loading.html'" ></div>
```

On JS side, before download start, set loading to true, when finished set it to false

```
$scope.loading = false; // when starts
$scope.loading = false; // when finished
```

Comment: my problem is that I dont know when download finish!because I dont know when the server finish to download

Comment: Then perhaps you should search for or ask a question about how to detect when a file download finishes.